# Artisan::call('migrate:fresh') on php script making the site unavailable for the first time and works on next reload

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan, laravel-seeding, artisan-migrate

I am using the below method

```php
private function migrate(BufferedOutput $outputLog)
{
    try {
            Artisan::call('migrate:fresh', $outputLog);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return $this->response($e->getMessage(), 'error', $outputLog);
        }

    return $this->seed($outputLog);
}
```

But for the first time (redirecting on PHP script to /install/database), the page does not appear, on refresh, it works as expected.

and the error is
[image]

Comment: You should not migrate the whole database at first place. The second thing - this operation takes a LOT of time and if you want your site available use queues: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues

Comment: Yes @PunyFlash, I agree it takes some time. actually, it is a part of rachidlaasri/laravel-installer this installation. I wanna run migrate programmatically on client's machine. is there any other way?

Comment: For modern days, it is not really convenient to implement visual installation - consider creating an installation script or/and docker image - they take much less effort from end user to run locally. For visual installation, you probably will need to create your own installer as rachidlaasri's package is abandoned

Comment: First time in the sense, It take some time to process

Comment: A little more context for the use case would better frame how to answer the question. It's hard to understand the context of what's calling the code that's here, and it's hard to see a use case where you would want a publicly available url that dumps all the tables in your database and re-runs all migrations. How is the above function being called, and what's the problem we're trying to solve for?

As @Sujith says below, if you visit a page, and it calls this function, it's going to take time to dump all the tables in your DB, and re-run migrations - likely longer than the browser timeout.

Comment: @KevinFoster Please read the above comments too, the code is part of rachidlaasri/laravel-installer. And the ultimate goal is to deploy the application on UI screen by any user (not a developer)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I have seen your issue might be, If you use "migrate:fresh", All the tables will be dropped and `up` methods will run which creates the fresh tables. This process will take some time. So, For the first time you reload the website, The migration will be running. Since the migration is in process, You will be getting "The site can't be reached" error.

To fix this, make sure to place a page displaying "Site is under development" till the migration completes. Then everything will work fine. But doing this kind of things are not suggestable.